# How can I configure a default server connection in SSMS for when I open any .sql script file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I want SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2012 to connect to a default server whenever I open any `.sql` file. How can I configure SSMS to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add "-S servername" to the shortcut you use to run SSMS. Check out this page for more detail: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/01/08/sql-server-using-ssms-commandline-parameters-guest-post-by-vinod-kumar-m/

Comment: leancz, thank you for your answer.It is not I need.When I open any *.sql file with MS Sql Server Management Studio ,it has to be opened on a server which set as default server

Comment: Please put that in your question, because it changes the proper answer. `-S` still works, but you'll have to add it to the registry for the command that handles `.sql` files (`HKCR\ssms.sql.<version>\Shell\Open\Command`).

Comment: Jeroen Mostert you are right.I have updated the question.
Thanks.

Comment: @musti: Please note that *the script file itself* is always opened on the machine where SSMS is running. I assume you mean that you want to automatically associate script files with an open *connection to* the server whenever the files are opened.

Comment: @stakx :I have more than one server connections.So,I just want to set one of this connections as my default server connection.When any script file opened, it has to connect to this server.

Answer (score 1):

**These changes are not supported by Microsoft. They could cause your installation to break and/or produce trouble with upgrades and service packs. Perform them at your own risk.**

You can do this by changing the command used to open .sql files. This requires a registry change -- [the usual caveats apply](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/136393). Open RegEdit and navigate to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssms.sql.11.0\Shell\Open\Command`. The value `(Default)` should read

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe" /dde
```

Change this to

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe" /s <server> "%1"
```

Where `<server>` is your desired default server.

Rename the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssms.sql.11.0\Shell\Open\Command\DdeExec` key to `_DdeExec` to prevent the shell from trying to open the file using DDE.

This has two effects: opening a .sql file will open them with a connection to the server you specified, and opening a file will always open a new instance of Management Studio (since we removed DDE).

If you do not remove the `/dde` parameter, opening other files will reuse your SSMS instance. However, they will use the last opened connection in that instance, not your default, which I imagine is surprising and potentially catastrophic.